# Neighborhoods Geo Query

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

Assuming I have multiple documents like the following (taken from the ElasticSearch documentation for `geo_shape`):

```
{
    "name": "Some Neighborhood",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there any query I can use that, given a point, returns the documents that contain that point? In other words, given a point I'm trying to quickly find out which neighborhood(s) it is in. Is there something else better sutied for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query it like this:

```
GET /my_index/landmark/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "location": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "point",
              "coordinates" : [4.896863,52.374409]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```